# Question about inductive definition of natural number

Tags: induction, natural-numbers

in "An Intro to Complex Analysis and Geometry, John P. D'Angelo', It has the following:

> Definition 3.4
>
>            A subset S of R is called inductive if whenever x∈S,
> then x+1 ∈ S.
>
> Definition 3.5 
>            The set of natural number N is the intersection of
> all inductive subsets of R that            contains 1.

I'm a little confused why the intersection of all inductive subsets of R that contains 1 is not the set of integers Z?

surely `... -3, -2, -1, 0, 1 , 2 ... is the one and only set that is the intersection of all inductive subsets of R that contains 1?

Comment: No, because if you intersect $\Bbb Z$ with $\Bbb N$ you just obtain $\Bbb N$. You are thinking of union

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $\Bbb N=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ is an inductive set and $\Bbb N\varsubsetneq\Bbb Z$. Therefore, $\Bbb Z$ cannot be the intersection of all inductive sets.